# trying to connect the postcss plugin to tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-3

I read instruction [PostCSS plugin Guidlines](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/main/docs/guidelines/plugin.md), wrote a simple plugin just for the test.

```
module.exports = (opts) => {
    return {
        postcssPlugin: "testplugin",
        Once(root) {
            console.log("Hello")
        },
    };
};
module.exports.postcss = true;
```

But I don't understand how I can connect it to tailwind. I know there is a postcss.config.js file is about the following content

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {}
    },
};
```

but all my attempts to add a plugin there lead to the error

Cannot find module 'testplugin'

i use tailwind 3.1.8 and postcss 8.4.16

[my github project](https://github.com/denisso/tailwind-expo/tree/testplugin)

I wrote [tailwind plugin](https://github.com/denisso/tailwind-expo/tree/tailwind-plugin) but the question remains open

Answer (score 0):

I used an [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) - ide development server that provides extensive functionality compared to native ES modules, for example, extremely fast hot module replacement (HMR). [it supports PostCSS](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css), for support this feature uses plugin [postcss-load-config](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-load-config). in which multiple syntaxes can be supported for objects and arrays. For objects, I still did not understand how to solve the problem, but it turned out with arrays

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        require("./postcss/testplugin")
    ],
};
```